# Jquery Steps : Disable tabbed navigation

Tags: tabs, jquery-steps

It's the first time I post here, even if I've been using this site for quite a long time now. Here is my issue : I'm using [jquery-steps](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) to create a validation/checkout form and I'd like to disable tab navigation, which allows users to jump between steps freely (from step 1 to step 3 for example). The tabs have to remain visible.

I realize that the solution might be quite simple, but I'm really stuck for now :/ ...

Thanks for your help, please excuse any english mistake !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already checked out the examples of [jquery-steps.com](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples)? If not, check out the *advanced form example* [here](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form)!
See also [this](http://www.rafaelstaib.com/post/How-to-create-a-Form-Wizard-using-jQuery-Steps) blog article which describes *How to create a Form Wizard using jQuery Steps* in detail.

Comment: thanks for your advices ! I did check all the examples (and documentation) available on jquery-steps.com, and read the article you just sent me. Unfortunately, my problem persist, I can't find a solution to disable tabbed navigation ! After some extended search, it might have something to do with aria-controller, that's all I could find :/ ... thanks anyway !

Answer (score 4):

Ok, after some extended research, I managed to find an alternative solution to my problem. I noticed that all headers are stored inside a ".steps" div. Thus, I added a new CSS property :

```
.steps {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

which disables all mouse actions for that particular class. I know it's not the cleanest solution possible but hey, it works for me :) !

(thx for your help rafael)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem today and managed to fix it by adding `disabled` class to the `li` elements inside the `div.steps`. Using `pointer-events` CSS was not a solution for me as had to disable certain step navigations at certain points. Although this approach might break your CSS i.e. if you have `disabled` and `done` classes and `disabled` styles are overwriting the `done` ones, nothing a bit of tweaking won't fix though.